# Catch final signal from QTimer object

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a simple PyQt script. When I click a button, it starts a QTimer object and increments a progress bar. What I want is to change the label of my text when my progress bar reaches 100%. It worked for me once, but I can't get it to work anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the main part of my code.

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):        
        self.setWindowTitle('QProgressBar demo')        

        self.timerButton = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.timerButton.clicked.connect(self.timerStart)

        self.timerObject = QTimer(self)
        #self.timerObject.destroyed.connect(lambda:self.timerButton.setText("Finished") )
        self.timerObject.destroyed.connect(lambda:print("Called" ))

        self.progressBar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(10, 20, 290, 25)

        self.timerButton.move(110,150)        
        self.progressBar.move(10,100)

        self.increment = 0

        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def headsUp(self):

        if(self.increment >= 100):
            self.timerObject.stop()                  
        else:
            self.increment += 1
            self.progressBar.setValue(self.increment)

        return


    def timerStart(self):
        if (self.timerObject.isActive()):
            self.timerObject.stop()
            self.timerButton.setText("Resume")
        else:
            self.timerObject.timeout.connect(self.headsUp)
            self.timerButton.setText("Pause")
            self.timerObject.start(100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

destroyed is only issued when you delete the object, that a `QTimer` peer does not imply that it is deleted from memory, therefore it does not emit that signal, a possible solution is to create a signal for the `QProgressBar` when the value takes the maximum value as shown below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class ProgressBar(QtWidgets.QProgressBar):
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProgressBar, self).__init__(*args, *kwargs)
        self.valueChanged.connect(self.on_valueChanged)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_valueChanged(self, val):
        if val == self.maximum():
            self.finished.emit()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):        
        self.setWindowTitle('QProgressBar demo')        

        self.timerButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.timerButton.clicked.connect(self.timerStart)

        self.timerObject = QtCore.QTimer(self)

        self.progressBar = ProgressBar(self)
        self.progressBar.finished.connect(lambda: print("Called" ))

        self.increment = 0

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        lay.addWidget(self.timerButton)
        self.resize(300, 300)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def headsUp(self):
        if self.increment >= 100:
            self.timerObject.stop()                
        else:
            self.increment += 1
            self.progressBar.setValue(self.increment)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def timerStart(self):
        if self.timerObject.isActive():
            self.timerObject.stop()
            self.timerButton.setText("Resume")
        else:
            self.timerObject.timeout.connect(self.headsUp)
            self.timerButton.setText("Pause")
            self.timerObject.start(100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another best option is to use `QTimeLine` and its `finished` signal:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets   


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):        
        self.setWindowTitle('QProgressBar demo')        

        self.timerButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.timerButton.clicked.connect(self.timerStart)

        self.timerObject = QtCore.QTimeLine(1000, self)
        self.timerObject.setFrameRange(0, 100)
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self)
        self.timerObject.frameChanged.connect(self.progressBar.setValue)
        self.timerObject.finished.connect(lambda: print("Called" ))
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        lay.addWidget(self.timerButton)
        self.resize(300, 300)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def timerStart(self):
        if self.timerObject.state() == QtCore.QTimeLine.Running:
            self.timerObject.stop()
            self.timerButton.setText("Resume")
        else:
            self.timerButton.setText("Pause")
            self.timerObject.resume()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't working because you are connecting to the timers `destoryed` signal, but the timer is not being destroyed.  To use this code as is, call `self.timerObject.deleteLater()` after you stop the timer.